# Is there a way to lazily assign a class property that requires type arguments?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a bit of a situation.

I have a class, which I can freely change, but needs to instantiated dynamically by some code that I don't control and which cannot pass the constructor generic type arguments. Also because of that dynamic code that does the instantiating the arguments to the constructor *must* be plain data (i.e. JSON serializable). This class has a property that is an instance of another class (that I have zero control over) that requires a generic type argument that is a subset of a union type and function arguments (i.e. can't be passed to the wrapping class' constructor) that I would like to lazily instantiate for those reasons.

Basically I need to be the bridge between two pieces of code I don't control.

Stripped down example:

```ts
type ABC = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

// I have no control over Foo.
class Foo<T extends ABC> {
  foo (x: T): void {
    console.log(x.repeat(2))
  }
}

// Bar cannot itself be generic, for the reasons given in the setup.
// I can change the implementation of Bar, but not Foo or the code
// that instantiates Bar
class Bar {
  foo?: Foo; // <-- Problem is here

  // I **do** control the code that calls this method
  createFoo<T extends ABC>(): void {
    this.foo = new Foo<T>()
  }
}
```

On it's own, `Foo` does what I expect:

```ts
const test1 = new Foo<'b' | 'c'>();
test1.foo('a'); // errors as expected
```

I tried to use the union itself as a placeholder...

```ts
class Baz {
  foo?: Foo<ABC>

  createFoo<T extends ABC>(): void {
    this.foo = new Foo<T>()
  }
}
```

But then:

```ts
const bz = new Baz();
bz.createFoo<'b' | 'c'>();
bz.foo?.foo('a') // Oops! this should fail like in the example above.
```

Is there any way to square this circle? I realize these are some odd constraints but I can't really change them.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=31&ssc=37&pln=29&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggQgYSgXigcgIZqgH3QI2zzQGM0BuAWACgaSAbDAZyagDEB7DgHgBUoIAD2AQAdgBNW8BAD4oAbxpQoAMy5QAFIIBcUXgEpdANw4BLcQqXKoJDqKYd6EAHT0OAcy3OAThEgZgDQAmfX0rAF8aSNpqAHpYqDgMbxsMUVEOYChTYCYIehUofGh3MQhvUxIAGihxOzQs21Fgb0ds+2A04FMA0ztnOkYWROTLamU1DgB+XU4Ocih4qG4AWhWoAAVW-CcAW2zWAAtyiBorEl8AiDm+AWExSVhEGQ1DKBNzMesoYEPTJmckxQUFEEAA7uwuHwXmFxlBotFBsxWEkAF5fVRcGaQnjSORLOoQJiiBpQMEcbwAaxqeWgxTcYLOcIuECuN34QhEEikz1exjMFkUcOUv3+gPUqFBEPZMIiUSZTSYWRESoAjMCpTjuGhCLh0GQYVRqCrgKrxRwNJg0PoFktyq1vKxmHdICQROIFXYlUV0ZLwSNUa8jfhUc4WWyoTqiPq0IaaCHzVNzZasPpFglRawmIcOABXegWFQYUz0GhAA)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to change types that are already instantiated without creating a new type In this case, Bar/Baz will conform to their instantiated type, and you can't change it from within the class.

You can get around this by instantiating a new type and returning that type instead. Either in a static method or as a regular method. We can cheekily use the `unknown` type to let people know there is a specific way to set `foo`.

So you can have something like this, which will return a merged type.

```js
class Bar {
  foo?: unknown;

  static createFoo<T extends ABC>(bar: InstanceType<typeof Bar>, foo: Foo<T>) {
    bar.foo = foo
    return bar as InstanceType<typeof Bar> & {foo: Foo<T>}
  }
}

const bar1 = new Bar();
const bar2 = Bar.createFoo(bar1, new Foo<'b' | 'c'>())
bar1.foo() //incorrect usage errors entirely
bar2.foo('a') //errors as expected
```

Or without Foo as a parameter

```js
class Bang {
  foo?: unknown

  static createFoo<T extends ABC>(fw: InstanceType<typeof Bang>) {
    fw.foo = new Foo()
    return fw as InstanceType<typeof Bang> & {foo: Foo<T>['foo']} // use ['foo'] index accessor since there is no constructor
  }
}

const bang1 = new Bang()
const bang2 = Bang.createFoo<'b'>(bang1)
bang1.foo('a') //error! type is unknown
bang2.foo('a') //error! cant use a
```

Or as a regular method

```js
class Fubar {
  foo?: unknown

  createFoo<T extends ABC>() {
    this.foo = new Foo()
    return this as InstanceType<typeof Fubar> & {foo: Foo<T>['foo']} // use ['foo'] index accessor since there is no constructor
  }
}

const fubar1 = new Fubar()
const fubar2 = fubar1.createFoo<'b'>()
fubar1.foo('a') //error! type is unknown
fubar2.foo('a') //error! cant use a
```

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N71krW)

As an detour discussion: this is inherently part of the design philosophy of Typescript, if you don't control the instantiation of Bar/Baz, how can you guarantee it instantiates Foo as you intend to? Also in the given example, there is no discriminant runtime differences between any of these functions, so it is a lot harder. Generally you could get around this by using [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) (using runtime values to discriminate and create [control flow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis)).

Comment: "How can you guarantee it instantiates Foo as you intend to?" I can't, that's why I want to delay it and have it done through a method that *my* code calls. "There is no discriminant runtime differences between any of these functions" I know. Honestly I think the other team I'm working with on this is making me bend over backwards and fight the compiler for a **very** marginal increase in safety, but I'm not willing to spend political capital to fight them on it. "Using runtime values to discriminate and create control flow" I guarantee that will break our bundle budget, that union has 100+.